# How to sync specific file with makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile which I generate according to a JSON file structure that I have. I.e. user will provide some JSON file in his project and by executing some CLI tool (which I will provide) it will generate a makefile based on the `project.json` file.

So far its working as expected, but here comes the tricky point. In case user changes the `project.json` file and the `makefile` has already been generated it will not catch the latest changes from the `project.json` file, is there a way to solve it with make file?  I need them to be synced...

**update**

lets this is my make file called `gmake`

```
include  gmake
gmake: project.json
    rtr init  $< $@

DIR := $(shell rtr execute start)
all: app1 app2

.PHONY: app1
App1:
    @echo “run app 1"

.PHONY: app2
App2:
    @echo "run app2”

Done: 
    rtr clean $(DIR)
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but it sounds like... either always run the CLI tool provided to regenerate the Makefile? Or it might actually also work to generate a rule into to that Makefile to have make do it.

Comment: You are including the file named `gmake` in itself? Sorry, but this does not make sense with make. Create a file named `Makefile`. In this file (`Makefile`) add the rule that generates file `gmake`, plus the line `include gmake`. And, by the way, `gmake` is not a very good choice, there are systems where the GNU make utility is named `gmake`. What about `Makefile.generated`, instead?

Comment: @RaynD Just to be sure: are you sure that your `rtr init` command works the way you use it? I mean, if you type `rtr init project.json gmake` in the command line, it works as expected? The arguments are the correct ones and in the correct order?

Comment: Actually, the first thing _make_ does is to check that the Makefile itself is up-to-date. This is exactly what you are requesting. Have a rule inside the _gmake_ makefile that says how to update _gmake_. _Make_ will do what you want. See [How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate with a top-level and a generated makefile. In the top-level `makefile`, you might have nothing but

```
all: makefile.gen
    @$(MAKE) -f $<

.PHONY: all

makefile.gen: project.json
    @yourCommand > $@
```

And the generated makefile (named `makefile.gen` here) is built whenever `project.json` changes. Make sure you change the last build rule to your needs such that that `makefile.gen` is generated by your command line tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GNU make, you could simply include this generated makefile in a top makefile:

```
include Makefile.generated

Makefile.generated: project.json
    json2makefile $< $@
```

make always tries to rebuild missing or out of date makefiles. And if it does it parses the makefiles again. From [How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) of the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html):

> To this end, after reading in all makefiles, make will consider each
>   as a goal target and attempt to update it. If a makefile has a rule
>   which says how to update it (found either in that very makefile or in
>   another one) or if an implicit rule applies to it (see Using Implicit
>   Rules), it will be updated if necessary. After all makefiles have been
>   checked, if any have actually been changed, make starts with a clean
>   slate and reads all the makefiles over again. (It will also attempt to
>   update each of them over again, but normally this will not change them
>   again, since they are already up to date.)

Comment: thanks, can you please explain why its better/diff then the first answer ,( I really want to understand which approach to take ) :)

Comment: @RaynD: Sure. Several reasons: 1) it's a built-in feature of make that has been designed exactly for this purpose. 2) One single make invocation instead of two, that is, better performance. 3) Simple, clean...

Comment: Can you explain what is the `host> cat Makefile
include Makefile.generated` , what is `nost` and why I need to `cat makefile`? thanks

Comment: `host> ` is the prompt of my shell. I use it to distinguish the commands I type in the terminal from the result they print. `cat Makefile` is the command that prints the content of file `Makefile`. I used it to show you the content of the `Makefile` I propose. But as this looks overcomplicated to you, let me modify my answer and remove this.

Comment: Well , I know what is `cat` means but I was confused with the context :) ..., so in my makefile I should put only `Makefile.generated: project.json
    json2makefile $< $@`  and add it like `all: Makefile.generated` and this should "listen" to the `projecet.json` changes , is that correct ? if not can you please show sample of makefile with this functionality?

Comment: The Makefile I show is all you need. No `all` target, nothing. But do not forget the `include Makefile.generated` line, as you did in your comment. The 3 non-empty lines are needed. The empty line is optional. With this set-up you can invoke any goal that is defined in your generated makefile (which goals I cannot guess).

Comment: Thanks, does the `Makefile.generated` in your example refer to my makefile that is created during generation i.e. should have the name of the file? i.e. it could be `gmake` etc?

Comment: I've tried it and it doesnt work, I've update my question with the makefile, please see if I miss someting...

Comment: @RaynD "_it doesn't work_" is not a very accurate description of your problem. May I suggest that you have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?